# Axios call returns me null but it works on postman

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to do the following axios call that work on postman but for whatever reason it returns me null when i do it on axios.

My axios call:

```
myCall() {
  axios
    .post("/my/call", {

     value: 'info',
     value2: 'info',
     value3: 'info'
     }
       )
    .then(res => {
      console.log("my call", res)
    });
},
```

In postman i have the following in my raw Body. There are no other parameters and the only header is content-type is application/json, which is the axios default.

```
{         "value": "info",
         "value2": "info",
         "value3": "info"
}
```

EDIT:

When i hard code the values the connection works just fine like below:

```
myCall() {
  axios
    .post("/my/call", {

     "value": "info",
     "value2": "info",
     "value3": "info"
     }
       )
    .then(res => {
      console.log("my call", res)
    });
},
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Are you sure the api route is correct? `/my/call` . Try entering the same url you entered in postman?

Comment: Use JSON.stringify({
     value: 'info',
     value2: 'info',
     value3: 'info'
     })
Store it in some variable and then pass in body.
Hope it should work.

Comment: Check you browsers network tab in the dev. tools, what is actually being sent?

Comment: No i didnt get any errors, it just returns null.
The api call is correct.
 JSON.stringify aint working

Comment: @igor i get either error 500 or a 200 with a null value

Comment: https://codepen.io/piyush_05/pen/YoxWMm
Check this

Comment: Your edit is identical to the original code you showed us.

Comment: @Quentin the "value" and info all have "" on them.

Comment: @Piyush i tried that but now i am getting a error 415

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man - That makes absolutely no difference.

Comment: appenretly it did because it brought me the values while the original one only brought me null.

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man - https://jsbin.com/pugobadula/1/edit?js,console - it really makes no difference. Something else must have changed.

Comment: maybe it is something in the back end. i got no idea.
I do have another question though. what if i wanted to pass a payload and save the response in a state? I am trying it but it aint working either.